# Execute Windows MBR repair on Ubuntu disk by mistake

Tags: boot, windows, boot-repair, mbr

I got notebook with broken Windows booting and I have found some tricks how to repair it. I copied CMD from web and paste it to terminal. Imediately after pasting the CMD it executes with wrong disk. Then I tried to restart my computer and it says:

```
No boot signature in partition.
```

The CMD was:

```
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

Does anyone know how to repair it?

Comment: I would imagine you have an EFI disk and `lilo` acts like it's processing an MBR disk. But I only use `grub` so it's just a guess. As the answer below suggests you should run `testdisk` if `lilo` documentation makes no mention of backing up the MBR (Master Boot Record) before it runs. Note both MRB disks and EFI disks utilize a Master Boot Record. (Confusing I know).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about boot stuff, but it sounds as if something has been overwritten. Try using `testdisk`. To do so, get a live CD or USB, boot into it, and in a terminal type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install testdisk
```

and then run

```
sudo testdisk
```

and try [this](https://www.interworks.com/blog/smatlock/2015/02/13/restore-damaged-or-corrupted-linux-partition-table) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to create bootable USB stick with same OS Ubuntu 16.04 and follow this: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

It restore grub...